# Make Opera wrap website text after I zoom

Tags: browser, opera, chromium

How could I force Opera to wrap text in websites after I zoom such that I no longer have to use the horizontal scroll bar? I'm also open to suggestions as to how this can be achieved on other browsers (especially Chromium-based ones).

Comment: Zooming doesn't affect the content, just how big or small it's displayed (just like a magnifying glass).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but if you zoom (deep enough, e.g 500%), the horizontal scroll bar does show up for me (e.g https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMDK) and it does not show at 100% zoom.

Comment: If you zoom in so that you can't see the whole screen/window, you need a scroll bar to see the parts that don't fit.  But that isn't changing the content.  If you use a magnifying glass, it doesn't change what you're looking at, it just changes how big it looks.  And if it's magnified, a smaller area fills your field of vision, so you have to move the view around to see everything.

Comment: I understand what you mean and I apologize for not formulating my statement clearly enough. I was actually reading through a page which was mostly text and on my phone, when I zoom, Opera does increase the font size, but, at the same time, moves wrapping text on the next line and does not create a horizontally scrollable page. I was wondering if the same could be done on the PC version.